# Is this example counts as cyclic referencing

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, system

I have a confusion with the cyclic references and communication patterns between view and controller(logic) classes.

Below image is a simple UML, which logic and view has their references and can talk with each other freely.

[Cyclic reference UML example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ouwp1.png)

But as I know, cyclic references are BAD, veryyy BAD. My friend showed me below UML as an solution to overcome this issue. We can just inherit these classes with interface and reference interfaces to this classes. As he said, its not counted as an cyclic referencing, but in my opinion its just an illusion.

[Basic solution UML example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTWre.png)

Back to the questions:

- Is coupling scripts still bad if they are cohesive little structures in the big chunk of our code.
- Does the second UML can be evaluated as better design, instead of first one. And is it cycling references?
- Even for the these two cohesive coupled class (but decoupled from all of the other classes in the codebase). Should I implement better solution?
  I ve read this blogpost which serves better solutions: https://www.sebaslab.com/the-truth-behind-inversion-of-control-part-i-dependency-injection/ ,  in the "Object Communication and Dependency Injection" section. Blogger mentiones 4 different communication method. The second UML is I think the first one he mentioned.
- Do you guys have better solution, both for view-logic object communication and general whole codebase object communication?

Comment: "But as I know, cyclic references are BAD, veryyy BAD." - according to?

Comment: Also... why are you using UML today?

Comment: According to what Ive read from interne, also one of my friend got minus point because of using cyclic references in the job interview. (it was a big company)
- Hard to maintain.
- Hard to scale futures
- Hard to collaborate with other developers
- Hard to debug
- There will be who calls who, who triggers logic first decisions
- Robert C. Martin says in the Clean Architecture book: "If there are cycles in the dependency structure, then the “morning after syndrome” cannot be avoided."

Comment: For the UML, I couldn t think of a way to tell my problem properly. Is this a problem? Any feedback appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would not say that cyclical dependencies are always bad. It implies a strong coupling between components, but in some cases is can be useful to use multiple strongly coupled classes instead of a single much larger class.

If you want to reduce coupling, interfaces is the typical way to go. But it might be sufficient with a single interface, i.e. either `IController` or `IView`, that should be sufficient to remove any cycles.

However, the common model when writing things like UIs is to follow a [Model-View-ViewModel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern), where the view references the view model, that in turn references the model. This does not really remove the circular references, since the view needs to know when the view model has changed. But it is abstracted by the use of events.

Events and delegates can often be used as a lighter weight alternative to interfaces. There are also patterns using event-managers, where you can send and listen to events of a specific type, without needing direct references between all the objects, but I'm somewhat skeptical of this, since I suspect it could be difficult to get an overview of what objects send and listens to some event-type.

In the end it usually depend on what specifically you want to do. Events are good when you want a fairly loose coupling, but are not well suited for complex interactions. For such cases interfaces might be better, but they do not really add much if classes are strongly coupled. As a rule of thumb when adding interfaces, you should ask yourself: What other implementations of this interface will be made? if the answer is none, then don't add it, at least not for the moment.

I would also not put to much stock on technical interviewers, since poor interview questions seem fairly common.